# how can i regist my own property to unity native animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to edit some custom proeprty of my own script, 'TopazObject' in Unity native system. But it doesn't appear to animation window.

Answer (score 0):

If the property is public then it is going to show up in the animation tab. Make sure its public. If you have a variable. If you want a variable with a custom class type to be visible there I think there is no way to do it.